How to INSERT to a table with AUTO_INCREMENT?
I'm trying to insert new users to a table in MySQL when they register. I am using a FlaskApp on PythonAnywhere.
Here is my query:
INSERT INTO user_profile (email, user_name, first_foo) VALUES (%s, %s, 0);

This is run from my flask_app code:
def connect_db(query, params):

    db_connection= MySQLdb.connect("<username>.mysql.eu.pythonanywhere-services.com","<username>","<password","<db_name>", cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

    cursor=db_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, params)
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    return result

connect_db(query, (email, username,))

Here is my table structure:
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id      | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email        | varchar(50) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| user_name    | varchar(15) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| first_foo    | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Unfortunately, I keep getting:
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

I have tried several queries including:
INSERT INTO user_profile (user_id, email, user_name, first_foo) VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, 0);
INSERT INTO user_profile (user_id, email, user_name, first_foo) VALUES (DEFAULT, %s, %s, 0);
INSERT INTO user_profile (user_id, email, user_name, first_foo) VALUES (0, %s, %s, 0);

but all return the same error.
If I run the first query in the MySQL console on Python Anywhere, the query is successful.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Can you please edit your question to include the Python code that executes your SQL query?

Are you sure that is the Python code you're running? Try adding something obvious like a print to be 100% sure.

try adding this db_connection.commit() after cursor.execute(query,params) you can never tell.

The first query in your question will work in mysql. If you get the error message in your question, then you either do not execute that query or your are executing it on a different table.

much better to show your table structure using show create table user_profile; it gives us a lot more info.  your first query is the correct way to do it; it sounds like you aren't running the version of your code you think you are or your python code isn't connecting to the database or server your console is.

Thanks everyone for your input. I do actually have a print statement in this function (I just removed it when posting to make it easier to read). I use this function in another query and so I know it definitely works.
@DerekRoberts - adding the commit worked!!!! Thank you so much!!! I'm always so amazed that the smallest addition can solve everything!! Do you want to put it as the answer and then I can accept it?

From the OP's comment this worked,
after each transaction such as INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries, adding commit() was pivotal after execute().
cursor = db_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, params)
db_connection.commit()  #  <- add this


unfortunately my English is not very good but.
If you correctly declared the column auto incrementable?
This could be solved by specifying which value the increment would start at:
ALTER TABLE YourTableName MODIFY user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


The table structure in the question shows it is auto_increment. And if it were not, INSERT INTO user_profile (user_id, email, user_name, first_foo) VALUES (0, %s, %s, 0); would work.
